# Why do I get hundred of "SUSPENDED" entries for a single SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to see what is expensive on my SQL Server. I use Activity Monitor and it shows a particular select as being expensive repeatedly.

However, I only run the query once!

I used this code to try and see what is going on:

```
DECLARE @tblVariable TABLE
                     (
                         SPID INT, 
                         Status VARCHAR(200), 
                         [Login] VARCHAR(200), 
                         HostName VARCHAR(200), 
                         BlkBy VARCHAR(200), 
                         DBName VARCHAR(200), 
                         Command VARCHAR(200), 
                         CPUTime INT, 
                         DiskIO INT, 
                         LastBatch VARCHAR(200), 
                         ProgramName VARCHAR(200), 
                         _SPID INT, 
                         RequestID INT
                     )

INSERT INTO @tblVariable
    EXEC Master.dbo.sp_who2

SELECT v.*, t.TEXT 
FROM @tblVariable v
INNER JOIN sys.sysprocesses sp ON sp.spid = v.SPID
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sp.sql_handle) AS t
WHERE v.[Status] = 'SUSPENDED'
ORDER BY BlkBy DESC, CPUTime DESC
```

And I see hundreds of "SUSPENDED" entries for my query (below are just a few).

Why are there so many? Should there be only 1?

```
SPID    Status  Login   HostName    BlkBy   DBName  Command CPUTime DiskIO  LastBatch   ProgramName _SPID   RequestID   TEXT
99  SUSPENDED                           LAWRENCE-SIM3   99      Matrix  SELECT              922 0   01/01 00:00:00  .Net SqlClient Data Provider                    99  2   SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [DATA].[1M].[FUT_LASTS_NOGAP]
                                WHERE [Symbol] LIKE 'ER4 Comdty%'
                                ORDER BY [utcDT] ASC
99  SUSPENDED                           LAWRENCE-SIM3   99      Matrix  SELECT              907 0   01/01 00:00:00  .Net SqlClient Data Provider                    99  2   SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [DATA].[1M].[FUT_LASTS_NOGAP]
                                WHERE [Symbol] LIKE 'ER4 Comdty%'
                                ORDER BY [utcDT] ASC
99  SUSPENDED                           LAWRENCE-SIM3   99      Matrix  SELECT              906 0   01/01 00:00:00  .Net SqlClient Data Provider                    99  2   SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [DATA].[1M].[FUT_LASTS_NOGAP]
                                WHERE [Symbol] LIKE 'ER4 Comdty%'
                                ORDER BY [utcDT] ASC
99  SUSPENDED                           LAWRENCE-SIM3   99      Matrix  SELECT              906 0   01/01 00:00:00  .Net SqlClient Data Provider                    99  2   SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [DATA].[1M].[FUT_LASTS_NOGAP]
                                WHERE [Symbol] LIKE 'ER4 Comdty%'
                                ORDER BY [utcDT] ASC
99  SUSPENDED                           LAWRENCE-SIM3   99      Matrix  SELECT              875 0   01/01 00:00:00  .Net SqlClient Data Provider                    99  2   SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [DATA].[1M].[FUT_LASTS_NOGAP]
                                WHERE [Symbol] LIKE 'ER4 Comdty%'
                                ORDER BY [utcDT] ASC
99  SUSPENDED                           LAWRENCE-SIM3   99      Matrix  SELECT              828 0   01/01 00:00:00  .Net SqlClient Data Provider                    99  2   SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [DATA].[1M].[FUT_LASTS_NOGAP]
                                WHERE [Symbol] LIKE 'ER4 Comdty%'
                                ORDER BY [utcDT] ASC
```

Comment: Presumably a parallel plan and you are getting a row for each task in the plan

Comment: Sorry - what does that mean?